# WES Evaluation for Canada PR

Tags: canada, resident-permit

Background: I wish to apply for PR in Canada.

I have completed my bachelor's degree (4-year course) in Computer Science from Mumbai University (oldest and most reputed University in Mumbai) and currently pursuing my final semester of a master's program in Business Administration (3-year course) from Jamnalal Bajaj Institute of Management Studies (deemed an autonomous university).

My final semester results are not expected before September 2018 i.e 4 months from now.

1. Can I initiate my WES evaluations with my bachelor's degree transcripts and partial master's degree transcripts (without the final semester results)?
2. Would this be valid for my PR application?

Please provide help and feedback. Thanks.

Comment: What’s your work experience? I don’t think you’re eligible for the Federal Skilled Worker program without that additionally you don’t get partial credit from WES. So you’ll get the points for a bachelors degree.

Comment: @nikhil: I have a working experience of 4+ years. I have got my WES evaluation done for bachelor's degree, now in process of master's degree evaluation.
Will I now be eligible for the FSWP?

Comment: yes, based on your work experience you’re eligible for the federal skilled worker program.